# ¿Cómo adapto un Closure a mi función en Swift4?

Tags: firebase, swift4

Mi problema es que cuando llamo la función me regresa un arreglo vacío, necesito enviar la respuesta hasta que ésta concluya
Esta es mi función.

```
    func getData () -> Array<Any> {
    db.collection("upload").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                self.objUpload = upload(
                    title: (data["title"] as! String?)!,
                    description:(data["description"] as! String?)!,
                    img:(data["img"] as! String?)!,
                    status:(data["status"] as! String?)!
                )
                self.arrayUpload.append(self.objUpload)
            }
        }
    }
    return self.arrayUpload
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Ya resolví mi duda, esta es la función actualizada:

```
     func getData (completionHandler:@escaping([upload]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    db.collection("upload").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            completionHandler(nil, err) //Response Error
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                self.objUpload = upload(
                                        title: (data["title"] as! String?)!,
                                        description:(data["description"] as! String?)!,
                                        img:(data["img"] as! String?)!,
                                        status:(data["status"] as! String?)!
                                       )
                self.arrayUpload.append(self.objUpload)
            }
            completionHandler(self.arrayUpload, nil) //Response Success
        }
    }

}
```

Espero les sirva a alguien.